# How can I extend msbuild to run a custom preprocessor on .cs files?

Tags: c#, msbuild

I have a custom program which preprocesses a C# file and generates a new C# file as output. I would like to invoke this from msbuild on each of the C# files in the project, then compile the output files instead of the original C# files. How would I go about this?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if there is an easy way to perform it with default msbuild tasks. But you can create your own task to do whatever you want:

[How To: Implementing Custom Tasks - Part I](http://blogs.msdn.com/msbuild/archive/2006/01/21/515834.aspx)

Also you can search for suitable tasks at "[MSBuild community tasks](https://github.com/loresoft/msbuildtasks)" site.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into using the "custom tool" code generation techniques in Visual Studio; there's an article about it on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cs/VsMultipleFileGenerator.aspx?display=Print)

Answer (score 0):

If your custom program is an executable the easiest way would be to call the executable with Exec:

```
<Exec Command="your executable" />
```

I would recommend writing a custom MSBuild task though. You can look at the [SDC Tasks](http://www.codeplex.com/sdctasks)  for samples on how to do it.